# How do I pull JSON data from this API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm reworking a weather APP I made using a different API. I've run into an issue where I can't pull anything from the JSON i get from said API. Am I using the wrong notation or is my JSON not actually being passed into my JS script correctly?

***Code on my local machine***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var long;
    var lat;
    var currentCity;
    var currentState;
    var country;

    $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://ip-api.com/json", function (data_init) { //access RESTFUL geo location API & set lattitude.longitude
        lat = data_init.lat;
        long = data_init.lon;
        currentCity = data_init.city;
        currentState = data_init.region;
        country = data_init.country;

        $(".heading").append("<h2>" + currentCity + "," + currentState + "<br>" + country + "</h2>");

        var api = "https://crossorigin.me/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/1246aa267663e22a4e428e4b20f0df5b/" + lat + "," + long;
        //Access weather API
        console.log(api);
        console.log(currentCity);
        console.log(currentState);
        console.log(country);

        $.getJSON(api, function (data) {

            var iconCode = data.currently.icon; //get Icon from API related to current weather conditions

            $(".message").append("<h4 id='tempData'>Current Temperature: " + data.currently.temp + "&#8451</h4>");
            $(".message").append("<h4>Conditions: " + data.weather[0].main + "</h4>");
            $("#reveal").on('click', function () { //click button
                data.main.tempData //on click convert temperature to farenheight
            });
            $(".message").append("<img id='conditions' src=" + iconUrl + ">");

            $("#tempData").hover(function () {
                $(this).fadeToggle('slow', function () {});
            });
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    //$("#reveal").on("click", function(){

    //});
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that the requests are actually completing successfully? If so did you check that the returned data is in the format you expected? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @PatrickEvans as it is the console only says currently is not defined. It does log the correct api url though. Which when I copy into my browser is the right JSON. This makes me think my notation is the issue

Comment: Says what is undefined? Did you log `data_init` and `data` to see if they actually contain your data?

Comment: @PatrickEvans it says 'currently' is undefined and yes both data and data_init log the right JSON

Comment: You have `data[currently].icon` that syntax is assuming you have some variable named `currently`, if you meant to access the `currently` property of `data` you do it like `data.currently` or `data["currently"]`, same thing happens a line after you have `data.currently[temp]` probably meant `data.currently.temp`

Comment: could you copy the sample response of both API here

Comment: It was exactly as @PatrickEvans said, my syntax for accessing the JSON data was wrong. Thank alot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what API you are using, but it looks like your callback is incomplete.

Callbacks are usually written in this format:

```
$.getJson("your url", function (err, data) { ... })
```

You probably forgot to handle err parameter on it.

Comment: Callbacks are only defined that way if they are going to be called with those arguments. Meaning if the code actually executing the callback is going to be passing in an error parameter and a data parameter, it doesn't have to be written like that. And [jQuery ajax callbacks aren't](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), the callback gets passed `data,status,xhr` in that order. You are thinking of callbacks, like those in nodejs, which pass an error argument first

Comment: This is why I said: "-I don't know what API you are using" and "-callbacks are usually written..."

Answer (score 0):

Answer: My syntax for accessing the JSON was incorrect. I was trying to access the property 'Currently'.It should be...

```
var iconCode = data.currently.icon; 
$(".message").append("<h4 id='tempData'>Current Temperature: "+data.currently.temperature+"&#8451</h4>");
```